# Reset existing data ids and identity after deleting data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have deleted some data in our database and I just want to know if it is possible to kind of reset the auto-increment value and reset also the id of the existing data that I have not deleted.

Say I have a user table that has about 100 data and I deleted data from 1-50. Is it possible to reset the id to start from 1 again and the auto-increment to start to 51 since that will be the next number?

I know about `DBCC CHECKIDENT (mytable, RESEED, 0)`. But if my understanding is correct it will only reset the next value of id of the next data that will be inserted in the table. What I want is to reset the existing ids as well.

Please let me know if this is possible.

**NOTE**

I understand that this is not really advisable to do. I am also aware that this might cause serious concern later on but I really would just like to know if it is possible. I would also keep in mind your advice and am grateful for it. Thank you

Comment: It is possible, but the question is why do you really want/need to do it?

Comment: Maybe what you need is to have a view that orders your rows in a certain way (by their auto incremented ID for instance), and add a column with the actual numbering of rows. Then index this view as you wish per your performance requirements, and _voilà_.

Comment: Have you any other tables referencing  this table by the `id` column?

Comment: What your trying to do isn't the point of an ID, nor of the `IDENTITY` property. An ID shouldn't change once it's been created.

Comment: @MichalB. Just to really reset the database since most of the deleted data are now rendered as invalid due to some changes and we cannot completely delete the other ones since it is being used in testing. Also for auditing of the data.

Comment: @Serg as of the moment ID is not being used as an FK or any reference of some sort.

Comment: Some very good points here - my answer was a how-to, not a question of why. But I agree that if you have business users that assume an auto-increment key is always continuous then you are setting yourself up to have problems down the track. Its easy to get gaps, and highly unlikely  that MAX(id)=COUNT(*) in the future.

Comment: I agree with @TomC. I will also add that you should not aim for MAX(id)=COUNT(*). I also do not understand how "resetting the database" will fix your issue. If deleted data renders as invalid (where?), then it's an issue with rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to fill in the gaps, you will have to do it manually, using Set identity_insert  on.

For example, if I want to change my rows 51-60 to be 1-10:

```
set identity insert mytable on
insert mytable(id, column1, column2)
select id-50, column1, column2 
from myTable 
where id between 51 and 60
set identity_insert mytable off
delete mytable where id between 51 and 60
```

Then reseed your ID and it should be good to go.

Comment: Also, you might need to "redirect" all existing foreign keys on other table that are referencing the rows that you are "moving".

Comment: @TomC thank you for showing that it is possible. I know this wouldn't really be advisable but it's good to know that it is possible to do.

Comment: No problem @vhie. You seem to have a handle on the "why not" part. But I have seen this done for code tables for example where people want the codes to be 1-n rather that whatever they might be after period of development and testing. Once its actually deployed, then certainly best to leave it alone.

Answer (score 3):

Don't waste time for doing this. The `ID` is for internal use. Also, if you have relations with other tables you need to update the IDs there, too.

You can create a view or just add in any `SELECT` statement `ROW_ID() OVER(ORDER BY [id])` and you will get an increment value without gaps.

Comment: @qotqn Thank you for this advice. I will keep this in mind.